# What's the electric field in a sphere with charge $Q$ and an inverse linear/square law density of charge?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

> In Classical Electrodynamics by Jackson problem 1.4 asks to find the electric field as a function of the radius of a sphere charged with a charge Q and with a spherically symmetric density that goes as $r^n$ with $n > -3$.

I found the expression of $\rho$ by normalizing it to the total charge Q.
I can calculate the electric field via Gauss law when $n \geq 0$ but in the other cases the integral of $\rho$ diverges. I was thinking of trying to exclude the singularity by excluding a sphere of radius $\epsilon$ and then making epsilon go to zero but not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you write, the expression for the charge density can be found by considering that the total charge within the sphere is $Q$. Indeed, if we define $\rho(r) = A r^n$ we have

$$
Q = 4 \pi A \int_0^{R_s} r^n r^2 dr = 4 \pi A \int_0^{R_s} r^{n+2} dr
$$

where $R_s$ is the radius of the sphere.

The Gauss law in this case takes the form

$$
4 \pi R^2 E(R) = \frac{4 \pi}{\epsilon_0} \int_0^R \rho(r) r^2 dr
$$

from which we get

$$
E(R) = \frac{1}{\epsilon_0 R^2} \int_0^R \rho(r) r^2 dr = \frac{A}{\epsilon_0 R^2} \int_0^R r^{n+2} dr
$$

The integral on the right-hand side diverges only for $n \leq -3$, which is not a issue given the text of the problem to solve.

For instance, if $\rho(r) = A r^{-2}$ we obtain

$$
E(R) = \frac{A}{\epsilon_0 R}
$$

whereas if $\rho(r) = A r^{-1}$ the field is

$$
E(R) = \frac{A}{2 \epsilon_0}
$$